# Excel SQL update based on values in 2 tables

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Let me start by saying that I am not using the right tools for the job but they are the only tools I have access to.

I am using Excel as a database that contains multiple tables with associated data.  Normally in a database, this data could be associated with a foreign key I believe however that is not the case with Excel.

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE items
batch_id  customer_id
1         1
2         1
3         2
```

and

```
TABLE customers
id      customer
1       cust1
2       cust2
```

I have a userform which only allows the user to select a customer by name.
What I would like to be able to do is update the customer_id in the items table based on a specific batch_id and a customer name.

This is what I have so far that isn't working.

```
UPDATE [items$]
SET [items$].customer_id=[customers$].id
INNER JOIN [customers$] 
ON [items$].customer_id=[customers$].id
WHERE [items$].batch_id='value1'
AND [customers$].customer='value2'
```

[UPDATE]

The following seems to be a little closer to answer but is giving me a 'Operation must use an updateable query.' error.

```
UPDATE items
SET items.customer_id=(
    SELECT FIRST(customers.id)
    FROM customers
    WHERE customers.customer=value2)
WHERE items.batch_id=value1;
```

I keep getting a 'Operation must use an updateable query error' with this but otherwise I see no reason why it shouldn't work

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to put in excel VBA. But the `update` syntax should be like (if u want to update all the rows)

```
Update items
set items.customer_id = (select customers.id 
                                     from customers inner join items 
                                     on customers.id = items.customer_id 
                                     where customers.id='Value2' 
                                     and items.batch_id='Value1');
```

Hope this might help u

Comment: My apologies, I had a mistake in my original query, I meant to be asking for [customers$].customer not .id

Answer (score 0):

Try with the  following once may be you will get your expected result.

But this is the case of SQL.

```
UPDATE items i
JOIN customers c ON i.customer_id = c.id
SET i.customer_id = c.customer
```

Comment: Once adding the WHERE statements it produces a syntax error